# Strange conversion warning under FreeBSD

Tags: gcc, warnings, freebsd, endianness

I have code like this:

```
#include <sys/endian.h>

int main(){
    uint64_t a = 100;
    be64toh(a);
}
```

When I try to port it under FreeBSD, I get:

```
# gcc x.cc -Wall -Wconversion -Wpedantic -lstdc++ -std=c++11
x.cc: In function 'int main()':
x.cc:5:2: warning: conversion to '__uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from '__uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
  be64toh(a);
  ^
x.cc:5:2: warning: conversion to '__uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from '__uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
x.cc:5:2: warning: conversion to '__uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' from 'uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

Why? Is there any way to avoid it?

Shall I use some other library other than sys/endian.h

Comment: I found bswap() gives the warning itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "gcc -E" brings answer. be64toh is superposition of inline function results in multiple casts 64->32->16. I suppose gcc want to inform about such conversions.

```
   (__builtin_constant_p((
   a
   )) ? (((__uint64_t)(__builtin_constant_p(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff) ? (((__uint32_t)((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) & 0xffff) ? (__uint16_t)(((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) & 0xffff)) << 8 | ((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) & 0xffff)) >> 8) : __bswap16_var(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) & 0xffff))) << 16) | ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) >> 16) ? (__uint16_t)(((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) >> 16)) << 8 | ((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) >> 16)) >> 8) : __bswap16_var(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) >> 16)))) : __bswap32_var(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) & 0xffffffff)) << 32) | (__builtin_constant_p(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32) ? (((__uint32_t)((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) & 0xffff) ? (__uint16_t)(((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) & 0xffff)) << 8 | ((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) & 0xffff)) >> 8) : __bswap16_var(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) & 0xffff))) << 16) | ((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) >> 16) ? (__uint16_t)(((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) >> 16)) << 8 | ((__uint16_t)(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) >> 16)) >> 8) : __bswap16_var(((__uint32_t)(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32)) >> 16)))) : __bswap32_var(((__uint64_t)((
   a
   ))) >> 32))) : __bswap64_var((
   a
   )))
```

Hint: use clang ;)

Comment: strange, under linux it works Ok, but not sure if C library is same.